# tslib: Selected device is not a touchscreen (must support ABS_X and ABS_Y events)

Tags: linux, touch

I set my tslib config as below:

```
root@NanoPC-T2:~# cat /etc/ts.conf
#module_raw friendlyarm-ts-input
module_raw input
module pthres pmin=1
module variance delta=30
module dejitter delta=10000
module linear
```

and....

```
root@NanoPC-T2:~# cat /etc/input.conf
TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/input/event1
#TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/touchscreen-1wire
```

but when I run ts_calibrate it shows me this error:

```
root@NanoPC-T2:~# ts_calibrate
TouchDevice: /dev/input/event1
xres = 1024, yres = 600
tslib: Selected device is not a touchscreen (must support ABS_X and ABS_Y events)
```

and touch not work.

.............................................................................

when I searched in net most of forum said you should edit the touch Linux source to solve this problem because it means your touchpad is multi touch but in config it is single touch.
But the default application in my device is running at statup of the linux and touch is working just in that program, but in my program is not work, I think maybe it needs ts_calibrate but whet I can run ts_calibrate it shows me this error.

.............................................................................

this is my device config:

```
root@NanoPC-T2:~# cat /dev/input/event1
·6Y)c56Y4c60·6Y=c0·6YDc9·6YIc·6YNc·6YU±55·6YbM61·6YlM·6YrM9·6YwM·6Y|M·6Y·6Y6Y6Y¯6Y´6Y¹6YÃé5·6YÌé61·6YÖé0·6YÜé9·6Yáé·6Yæé·6Yµ5·6Y¿60·6YÈ0·6YÏ9·6YÓ·6YÙ·6Y¿      ·6YÇ
^C
root@NanoPC-T2:~# cat /proc/bus/input/devices
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0001 Product=0002 Version=0100
N: Name="Nexell Keypad"
P: Phys=nexell/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/nxp-keypad/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event0
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="it7260_ts"
P: Phys=I2C
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event1
B: PROP=0
B: EV=b
B: KEY=2000000 1000 40000800 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=2650000 0

I: Bus=0013 Vendor=dead Product=beef Version=0101
N: Name="fa_ts_input"
P: Phys=input(ts)
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event2
B: PROP=0
B: EV=b
B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 1000 40000800 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=1000003

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=1c4f Product=0032 Version=0110
N: Name="SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse"
P: Phys=usb-nxp-ehci-1.1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/nxp-ehci/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event3
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=1f0000 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B: REL=103
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="I2S-ES8316 Headphone Jack"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/es8316-audio.0/sound/card0/input4
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event4
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

root@NanoPC-T2:~# cat /sys/devices/virtual/input/input1/event1/uevent
MAJOR=13
MINOR=65
DEVNAME=input/event1

root@NanoPC-T2:~# evtest /dev/input/event1
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x18 vendor 0x0 product 0x0 version 0x0
Input device name: "it7260_ts"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 139 (KEY_MENU)
    Event code 158 (KEY_BACK)
    Event code 172 (KEY_HOMEPAGE)
    Event code 217 (KEY_SEARCH)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 48 (ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max       16
    Event code 50 (ABS_MT_WIDTH_MAJOR)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max        2
    Event code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max     1024
    Event code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max      600
    Event code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max        5
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1495091024.272836, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 221
Event: time 1495091024.272845, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 343
Event: time 1495091024.272853, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 48 (ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR), value 8
Event: time 1495091024.272859, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 0
Event: time 1495091024.272862, ++++++++++++++ SYN_MT_REPORT ++++++++++++
Event: time 1495091024.272867, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1495091024.295424, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 226
Event: time 1495091024.295450, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 343
Event: time 1495091024.295472, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 48 (ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR), value 8
Event: time 1495091024.295490, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 0
Event: time 1495091024.295506, ++++++++++++++ SYN_MT_REPORT ++++++++++++
Event: time 1495091024.295522, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1495091024.316637, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 229
Event: time 1495091024.316644, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 343
Event: time 1495091024.316651, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 48 (ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR), value 8
Event: time 1495091024.316655, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 0
Event: time 1495091024.316658, ++++++++++++++ SYN_MT_REPORT ++++++++++++
Event: time 1495091024.316661, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1495091024.336736, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 229
Event: time 1495091024.336742, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 343
Event: time 1495091024.336749, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 48 (ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR), value 4
Event: time 1495091024.336754, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 0
Event: time 1495091024.336757, ++++++++++++++ SYN_MT_REPORT ++++++++++++
Event: time 1495091024.336760, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1495091024.356671, ++++++++++++++ SYN_MT_REPORT ++++++++++++
Event: time 1495091024.356675, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It solved, I should use ts-mt.conf instead of ts.conf

```
# Capacitive screen 
TSLIB_CONFFILE = / etc / ts-mt.conf 
#Resistive screen 
# TSLIB_CONFFILE = / etc / ts.conf
```